# Setup delay when MouseOut on function

Tags: jquery

I need to add to this some delay when mouse will leave that element? SetTimeout not working inside that "if" :-/

```
$('#tools .has-tooltip').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('#tools .has-tooltip').removeClass('hover')
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}).on('mouseout', function (e) {
    if ((!$(e.target).is('input')) && (!$('input').is(":focus"))) {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I assume you have a good reason to use javascript here instead of the CSS `:hover` rules.)

`setTimeout` will work -- you're probably losing the context for `this`.  If you can use ES6 formatting, you can preserve the existing `this` with a fat arrow function:

```js
var timeoutID = false; // We'll use this to cancel any existing timeouts before setting a new one

$('#tools .has-tooltip').on('mouseover', function() {
  if (timeoutID) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }

  $('#tools .has-tooltip').removeClass('hover')
  $(this).addClass('hover');
}).on('mouseout', function(e) {
  if ((!$(e.target).is('input')) && (!$('input').is(":focus"))) {
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.hover {
  background-color: #FFC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tools">
  <div class="has-tooltip">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, store `this` in a temporary variable that can be used in the setTimeout function:

```
...
var self = this;
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $(self).removeClass('hover');
},1000);
...
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not know why, but this script will remove the "hover" class even though mouseout has not been done, basicly, I will put mouse on #tools .has-tooltip and in 1 second the "hover" will be removed, even if I will not move anywhere :-/

Comment: the problem was been in "mouseout", beacause I am using it for children elements, so with mouseleave it working very well, thank you again :)